# How to extract a row of Mat matrix into a new one

Tags: opencv

Assuming a `Mat img(512,512,CV_32F)`, then how to put a specific row, say 10th, in `img` into another mat, say img_r10, of the same type? Are there relevant functions  to do that?

Comment: Something like [`cv::Mat::row`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4b22e1c23af7a7f2eef8fa478cfa7434)? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the block access method (Table 4-7 in Learn Opencv 3 https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-opencv-3/9781491937983/ch04.html) of `cv::Mat`, that is `cv::Mat::row` here.

Similar posts are found here: [Copy select rows into new matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994171/copy-select-rows-into-new-matrix) and https://answers.opencv.org/question/2139/extract-specified-row-from-cvmat/